# Delete specific cookies from webengine JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, session-cookies, httpcookie, javafx-webengine

I would like to delete some specific HTTP only cookies generated by the JavaFX webengine.
Chrome browser allows us to delete httponly cookie which means this is programmatically possible.

I am able to delete all cookies using

```
java.net.CookieManager manager = new java.net.CookieManager();
manager.getCookieStore().removeAll();
```

Using this the user is logged out from my application as well. I want to be able to delete all cookies except the one generated for my application.
Or is it possible to delete the same cookies using javascript.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Anyone looking for the solution. Here it is.
Set this right at the start of the main method of javafx.

```
cookieManager =  new CookieManager();
cookieManager.setCookiePolicy(CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL);
CookieHandler.setDefault(cookieManager);
```

Then on any event(I did it onclick of a button) call this

```
CookieStore cookieJar =  Main.cookieManager.getCookieStore();
List<HttpCookie> cookies =  cookieJar.getCookies();

for (HttpCookie ck: cookies) {
if(ck.getName().equals("JSESSIONID")){
          System.out.println("JSESSIONID");
   }else{
          ck.setMaxAge(0);
          System.out.println("CookieHandler retrieved cookie: " + ck);
   }
}
```

I hope this helps someone cause I spent the entire day looking for the solution.

Comment: He Hemal, can you please tell me the meaning of "Main.cookieManager.getCookieStore()".

Answer (score 0):

[According to docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.2.1/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getCookies%28%29) `getCookies()`

> Returns an array containing all of the Cookie objects the client sent with this request. This method returns null if no cookies were sent.

So, you should be able to iterate through the list of cookies returned and identify the elegible(s) to be deleted:

```
Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();

for (int i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
  String name = cookies[i].getName();
  String value = cookies[i].getValue();
}
```

If no you can override the cookie adding it with the `addCookie(Cookie)`

Comment: request.getCookies() gives me cookies that I have generated. I want access to other cookies as well.